# Onchange Populate Select Option PHP Ajax Html Jquery

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax

Why i am getting
Warning: Undefined array key "officeId" in C:\xampp\htdocs\scheduler\classes\Setting.php
Also it wont show on assemblyid

When i inspect my code and go to the network the data is already loaded but it still wont populate the on my assemblyid

My code in index

```
        <select class="custom-select" name="o_id" id="officeid" >
            <option value="0"></option>
                <?php  
                $hall_qry = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM `office_hall` WHERE o_id !=0  order by `office_name` asc");
                        while($row = $hall_qry->fetch_assoc()): ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $row['o_id'] ?>"><?php echo $row['office_name'] ?></option> 
                        <?php
                        endwhile; 
                        ?>
        </select>
        <br><br>
        <select class="custom-select" name="assemblyid" id="assemblyid"> 
           <option value = ""></option>             
        </select>

<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#officeid').change(function(){
        var officeid = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
            url:_base_url_+"classes/Setting.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:{officeId:officeid},
            dataType:"text",
            success:function(data)
                {
                $('assemblyid').html(data);
                }
            });
    });
});
</script>
```

Setting.php

```
<?php
require_once('../config.php');


$hall_qry = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM assembly_hall WHERE o_id = '".$_POST['officeId']."'");
while($row = $hall_qry->fetch_assoc()): ?>
    
        <option value="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>"><?php echo $row['room_name'] ?></option>
        
        <?php
 endwhile; 
        ?>
```

[image]

Comment: Are you sure it is complaining about officeid or officeId? They are different. Remember that in PHP, variable names and indexes etc are case sensitive.

Comment: complain in officeId in the php

Comment: It appears you have fixed the officeId error ( which was a typo) now all you need to do is fix $('assemblyid').html(data); which should be $('#assemblyid').html(data); as it is an ID. And watc h out for your Variable Name Case... Variable names etc are Case Sensitive.........Do you want assemblyid (all lower case) OR assemblyId ( Camel Case?) Do not mix these up!